# Remove .php extension from url with htaccess only for specific pages

Tags: .htaccess, hashtag

I am using .htaccess for remove .php from url,this is code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This works fine, for this: `www.domain.com/about`, now is there possibility if there is hash tag in url, etc: `www.domain.com/about.php#page1`, to don't remove .php extension, so only if there is # tag, url need to have .php extension, in any other case .php extension not needed.

Tnx,

P

Comment: Post the solution as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

----Solved---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```